# PersistableBundle persistentState в методе onCreate Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk

Ранее метод onCreate в Android Studio всегда создавался таким:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}
```

С выходом Android Studio 3.0 в нем появился новый аргумент PersistableBundle persistentState:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);

}
```

Вопрос: для чего? Какую функцию он выполняет?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `PersistableBundle` - это разновидность `Bundle`, который содержит только базовые типы: `String, int, boolean` и проч.
2. Параметр `PersistableBundle` будет всегда `null`, кроме тех случаев, когда `Activity` был восстановлен после перезагрузки.
3. После перезагрузки могут быть восстановлены только `Activity` промаркированные как `android:persistableMode="persistAcrossReboots"` в манифесте.

Answer (score 4):

Это не в методе `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` появился новый аргумент, а это появился ещё один метод (в API 21), который принимает два параметра.

[image: Скриншот Android Studio]
Клик по данной иконке в Android Studio откроет реализацию класса `Activity`, в котором данный метод определён и описан с помощью Java Docs. Также это описание можно найти в официальной [документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle,%20android.os.PersistableBundle)).

Конкретно там сказано, что это тоже самое, что и `onCreate(android.os.Bundle)`, но вызывается в активити, у которых в Android Manifest прописан атрибут `persistableMode` со значением `persistAcrossReboots`.

То есть, если этот атрибут у вас не прописан в манифесте, вы по прежнему должны использовать метод `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`.